# Can I change the Java package of a WebService Client?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, websphere

So, my JAVA application is connected to different WebServices that were developed inhouse and all 3 of them are packaged under org.tempuri

This is the default namespace I believe and when the wizard creates the Java packages it places them under org.tempuri..
I wanted to change them to give them meaningful names but then my app exploded :(

Can I just go into the .wsdl and change the namespace and repackage it all?  Or some way that I can change package "org.tempuri" to "com.abc.ws.imageservices"

I would do a trial and error on my free time, but it would take me a couple of days since the job has other priorities..., so I'm hoping that an answer is faster.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [wsimport](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html).

Wsimport will allow you to import directly from a WSDL and one of the parameters in the output project.

```
wsimport -p com.abc.ws.imageservices -d src/ -wsdllocation http://my.wsdl.com/location?WSDL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using RAD or WID, yes.. it can be done really fast if you refactor the namespace (which would change the WSDL) and then you just have to regen.